# Memory leak in the GSL

Tags: memory-leaks, gsl

I am using the GnuWin32 package of the GSL to implement some nonlinear fitting in a piece of code I am writing. I noticed recently there was a memory leak in my code, which I traced back to a single function which invokes the GSL's implementation of the Levenberg–Marquardt algorithm for nonlinear least-squares fitting.

The function itself is simple enough that I am confident there is no memory leak in my section of the code - which leaves only the GSL code itself as the source of the problem.

Are there any known memory leak issues in the GSL that I am unaware of?

The function in question is part of a github repo you can find [here](https://github.com/shadowk29/CUSUM). The function is in stepfit.c, and I have included a copy of the relevent parts below, with some of the fluff removed for the sake of reading.

```
void step_response(event *current, double risetime, uint64_t maxiters, double minstep)
{
#ifdef DEBUG
printf("StepResponse\n");
fflush(stdout);
#endif // DEBUG
if (current->type == STEPRESPONSE)
{
    //set up solver
    const gsl_multifit_fdfsolver_type *T;
    gsl_multifit_fdfsolver *s;
    int status = GSL_CONTINUE;
    uint64_t i,iter = 0;
    uint64_t p = 7;
    uint64_t n = current->length + current->padding_before + current->padding_after;
    double *weight;
    weight = calloc_and_check(n,sizeof(double),"Cannot allocate weight array");

    gsl_matrix *covar = gsl_matrix_alloc (p, p);

    gsl_multifit_function_fdf f;


    [...] //get data for initial guess


    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if (i < start)
        {
            weight[i] = 1;
        }
        else if (i < end)
        {
            weight[i] = 0.3;
        }
        else
        {
            weight[i] = 1;
        }
    }
    struct data d = {n, current->signal,weight};
    //generate initial guess
    gsl_vector *x = gsl_vector_alloc(p);
    gsl_vector_set(x,0,baseline);
    gsl_vector_set(x,1,sign < 0 ? maxsignal - minsignal: minsignal - maxsignal);
    gsl_vector_set(x,2,start);
    gsl_vector_set(x,3,risetime);
    gsl_vector_set(x,4,sign < 0 ? maxsignal - minsignal: minsignal - maxsignal);
    gsl_vector_set(x,5,end - current->length/2);
    gsl_vector_set(x,6,risetime);


    f.f = &expb_f;
    f.df = &expb_df;
    f.fdf = &expb_fdf;
    f.n = n;
    f.p = p;
    f.params = &d;
    //allocate solver
    T = gsl_multifit_fdfsolver_lmsder;
    s = gsl_multifit_fdfsolver_alloc (T, n, p);
    gsl_multifit_fdfsolver_set (s, &f, x);

    //iterate solver
    while (iter < maxiters && status == GSL_CONTINUE)
    {
        iter++;
        status = gsl_multifit_fdfsolver_iterate (s);
        if (status)
        {
            break;
        }
        status = gsl_multifit_test_delta (s->dx, s->x,1e-3, 1e-3);
    }


    double i0 = FIT(0);
    double a = FIT(1);
    uint64_t u1 = FIT(2);
    double rc1 = FIT(3);
    double b = FIT(4);
    uint64_t u2 = FIT(5);
    double rc2 = FIT(6);
    double residual = 0;

    [...] //sanity chewcking and storing/printing results

    gsl_multifit_fdfsolver_free (s);
    gsl_matrix_free (covar);
    gsl_vector_free(x);
    free(weight);
    if (status != GSL_SUCCESS)
    {
        current->type = BADFIT;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post a small and simple bit of sample code, perhaps the function itself?

Comment: Certainly. The function it a bit long, but it's fairly readable. I'll also edit with a link to the github repo.